# display month names from array

Tags: php, arrays, view, yii2

Hi i want to do some links with months names:

So on start I tried to genereate only months names in model in function where i loop this in for loop. But when i tried to display this function in my index i have only one first month name(styczeń). I dont know where i made a mistake. Maybe someone can help me? This is my function in model:

```
public function getPosts() {
        $month = array(1=>Yii::t('app', 'Styczeń'), Yii::t('app', 'Luty'), Yii::t('app', 'Marzec'), Yii::t('app', 'Kwiecień'), Yii::t('app', 'Maj'), Yii::t('app', 'Czerwiec'), Yii::t('app', 'Lipiec'), Yii::t('app', 'Sierpień'), Yii::t('app', 'Wrzesień'), Yii::t('app', 'Październik'), Yii::t('app', 'Listopad'), Yii::t('app', 'Grudzień'));
        for ($monthNum = 1; $monthNum <= 12; $monthNum++) {
            return $month[$monthNum];
        }
    }
```

And in my view:

```
<?= Html::a($blog->getPosts(), Url::to(['index'])) ?>
```

This display me only one first monthname i want to display all 12 months. Someone can help me?

Comment: You should learn the basics of programming before using Yii2...

Comment: i tired to learn php and yii2 but arrays is now hard to me

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php

Comment: so You not tell me where I made a mistake? I think I learned a lot when i asked on this forum and I learn new things i think this forum is for begginers too.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a value here: `return $month[$monthNum];`. After calling `$blog->getPosts()` your `getPosts()` gets executed and returns the first month. It's done then. You can't have a function returning more than one value in this way.
Instead of writing `return $month[$monthNum];` you could for example build up a string in your function:

```
$string = '';
for ($monthNum = 1; $monthNum <= 12; $monthNum++) {
    $string .= $month[monthNum];
}
return $string;
```

You'll notice that there'd be more work to do than only these five lines to get a nice output. There are many more ways (and maybe better ways) to get what you want.

Comment: but it returnt me one big string i want to return each mont name is separate value?